# Objective-C: Can't Get Online Video To Stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, html5-video

This worked prior to updating Xcode to v. 7.  Now I can't get video to stream.

Here's the code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *mpc;
}

@end

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"];

    mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    [[self view]addSubview:mpc.view];

    [mpc setFullscreen:YES];

    [mpc play];
}
```

For the .h file, I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

And I've imported the Media Player Framework.

The App works, but when it launches I only get a blank video player.  The video should auto-play, but it doesn't.  It doesn't play even when I tap the play button.

Any help would be awesome.  This is a working link for anyone to play with to see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks all,

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the URL is http, and assuming you are already using the iOS 9 based on the date of posting.

I believe your problem is in the `App Transport Security` which blocks http urls.

You can try to add this in the `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use  MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming Instead of MPMovieSourceTypeFile.

[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];